# How to properly handle the stdio of a spawned child_process?

Tags: python, node.js, io, child-process

I was working with child processes. I am making a game (which is pretty much in its last stages of completion) and now I have discovered a serious issue.

Basically, In the game, I have a javascript based server that uses child_process to `spawn` a sub-process that runs a python script. The python script handles the game mechanics, and the js code handles the server-client system. I need a communication system between the js and my python code. Using docs and other resources, I have successfully set up such a system, but after some time, it stops working.

Here is the code to replicate the issue: -

Javascript (temp.js):

```
"use strict";

const childProcess = require('child_process');

let pythonProcess = childProcess.spawn("python", ["temp2.py"], {cwd: "./private/PythonScripts/Temp/"});

pythonProcess.stdin.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
pythonProcess.stdout.setEncoding("utf-8");

const writeString = "" +
  "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" +
  "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" +
  "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" +
  "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" +
  "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" +
  "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" +
  "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" +
  "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\n";  // 8x  128 Zeros

pythonProcess.stdout.on("error", (err) => {
  console.log("Stdout Error");
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});

let count = 0;

setInterval(() => {
  count++;
  console.log(count);
  pythonProcess.stdin.write(writeString, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error during writing");
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
}, 100);
```

Python (3.10.x) (temp2.py):

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
                    handlers=[logging.FileHandler('temp.log', 'w+', 'utf-8'), logging.StreamHandler()],
                    level=logging.INFO)

tempLogger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tempLogger.info("Started")
    while True:
        inp = input()
        tempLogger.info(inp)
```

DIRECTORY STRUCTURE:

```
temp.js
private
 |
 |-> PythonScripts
      |
      |-> Temp
           |
           |-> temp2.py
           |-> temp.log
```

When we run this code, we will see that the js successfully continues to write (I assume so because the `err` is always `undefined`), but the python will only log the input only 79 times.

My hunch is that the issue is related to buffer/pipe overflow and they are not getting drained, but after searching all docs for child_process and logging/input for python, I was not able to figure out where the issue is, that is blocking the communication between the scripts.

What can I do so that the data flow doesn't get stuck like it is getting stuck now.

Answer (score 0):

So, I have finally figured out the issue.

The issue is, the way I have set up the logger, the logger will write in the log file, as well as in the console.

But since the process is created using child_process, we are not able to see that. In my main code, I have set up a callback for `pythonProcess.stdout.on("data", (data) => {...});`, but we still cannot see those logs. When I ran the script independently, then I noticed that additional printing to the console. Finally, I was able to see the logs by setting up a handler for `pythonProcess.stderr.on("data", (data) => {...});`.

There are two fixes: -

Just stop the logger from logging into the console. Python code for that will be: -
(Don't use `basicConfig()`)

```
import logging.handlers

tempLogger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
tempLogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler('temp.log', 'w+', 'utf-8')
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(fmt='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
tempLogger.addHandler(handler)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tempLogger.info("Started")
    with open("temp.txt", "r") as in_file:
        while True:
            for line in in_file.readlines():
                if line != "":
                    line = line.rstrip("\r\n")
                    tempLogger.debug(line)
```

Setup a handler for stderr of the child process like I have mentioned above `pythonProcess.stderr.on("data", (data) => {...});`. This will clear the stderr buffer, and the logging will now get stuck.